# Dependencies azure devops yaml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks, build-pipeline

I can't understand why dependencies don't work. I need to fix *- task: cake@2* and other commented tasks. Now they looks like jobs, but I need to convert them into tasks.
Here that task:

```
 - task: Cake@2
            displayName: Restore FE and Sitecore modules
            condition: Or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['ChangedFiles.BE'], 'true'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
            inputs:
              script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
              target: "Server :: Restore"
              verbosity: "Quiet"
              Version: "1.3.0"
```

Here's the whole code

```
name: test-build$(Rev:.r)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*

  paths:
    exclude:
      - "environment/**/*"

schedules:
- cron: 0 19 * * 1-5
  displayName: evening-deployment
  branches:
    include: 
    - develop
  always: false # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

variables:
  - group: shared-variables
  - name: ArtifactsLocation
    value: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/output"
  - name: NUGET_PACKAGES
    value: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages"

stages:
  - stage: build
    displayName: Build solution
    jobs:
      - job: Init
        steps:
          - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'PullRequest') }}:
              - template: /environment/azure/templates/steps/validate-pr-title.yml
          - task: gitversion/setup@0
            displayName: Installing GitVersion tool
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "5.8.1"
      
          - task: ChangedFiles@1
            displayName: check
            condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
            inputs:
              rules: |
                [FE]
                **/*.json
                **/*.ts
                **/*.js
                **/*.tsx
                **/*.scss
                **/*.html
                **/*.css
                
                [BE]
                **/*.csproj
                **/*.cs
                **/*.yml
                **/*.yaml

                [SCContent]
                **/*.json
                **/*.yml
                **/*.yaml
          
          - task: GitVersion@5
            displayName: Generate GitVersion
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "5.8.1"
              runtime: "full"
              configFilePath: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/GitVersion.yml"
          
          - script: |
              echo deployInt: $(deployInt)
              echo deployQa: $(deployQa)
            displayName: Show variables for debug
            condition: eq(variables['system.debug'], 'true')

      - job: SitecoreCode
        dependsOn: Init
        steps:
          - task: UseNode@1
            displayName: Install correct Node.Js version
            inputs:
              version: "16.x"

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache cake packages
            inputs:
              key: 'cake | "$(Agent.OS)"'
              restoreKeys: |
                cake
              path: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/tools"

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache nuget modules
            inputs:
              key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**'
              restoreKeys: |
                nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
                nuget
              path: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/packages"

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache nuget package reference modules
            inputs:
              key: 'nuget_pr | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/packages.lock.json'
              path: "$(NUGET_PACKAGES)"
              restoreKeys: |
                nuget_pr | "$(Agent.OS)"
                nuget_pr

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache node modules
            inputs:
              key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/package-lock.json'
              restoreKeys: |
                npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
                npm
              path: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/node_modules"

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache client node modules
            inputs:
              key: 'client_npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/rendering/package-lock.json'
              restoreKeys: |
                client_npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
                client_npm
              path: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/rendering/node_modules"

          - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
            displayName: Download license
            name: licenseFile
            inputs:
              secureFile: "license.xml"

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: Place license file under /src folder
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                Move-Item $(licenseFile.secureFilePath) "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/" -Force

          - template: /environment/azure/templates/steps/set-assembly-version.yml  

          - task: Cake@2
            displayName: Restore FE and Sitecore modules
            condition: Or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['ChangedFiles.BE'], 'true'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
            inputs:
              script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
              target: "Server :: Restore"
              verbosity: "Quiet"
              Version: "1.3.0"

      # - job: Restore_BE
      #   displayName: Restore BE
      #   dependsOn: Init
      #   condition: Or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.FE'], 'true'),ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      #   steps:          
      #     - task: Cake@2
      #       displayName: Restore FE and Sitecore modules
      #       inputs:
      #         script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
      #         target: "Server :: Restore"
      #         verbosity: "Quiet"
      #         Version: "1.3.0"

                      
      # - job: Restore_FE
      #   displayName: Restore FE
      #   dependsOn: Init
      #   condition: Or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.FE'], 'true'),ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      #   steps:          
      #     - task: Cake@2
      #       displayName: Restore FE and Sitecore modules
      #       inputs:
      #         script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
      #         target: "Client :: Restore"
      #         verbosity: "Quiet"
      #         Version: "1.3.0"
          
            # drop empty config to make sure that JSS app picks settings from env vars
          - powershell: |
              $MyJsonHashTable = @{
                'sitecore' = @{
                    'instancePath' = ''
                    'apiKey' = '$(JssApiKey)'
                    'deploySecret' = ''
                    'deployUrl' = ''
                  'layoutServiceHost' = ''
                }
              }
              $MyJsonVariable = $MyJsonHashTable | ConvertTo-Json
              Set-Content "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/rendering/scjssconfig.json" $MyJsonVariable
              Write-Host ('{0}vso[task.logissue type={1}]{2}' -F '##', 'warning', "It would be nice to make app use SITECORE_API_KEY env var instead of API KEY in this file");
            displayName: Generate scjssconfig.json with default API key
            # TODO: Fix application to read SITECORE_API_KEY Variable

      # - job: Build_BE
      #   displayName: Build BE
      #   dependsOn: Init
      #   condition: Or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.BE'], 'true'),ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      #   steps:
      #     - task: Cake@2
      #       displayName: Generate and Build FE and Sitecore
      #       inputs:
      #         script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
      #         target: "Server :: Build"
      #         verbosity: "Quiet"
      #         arguments: '--BuildConfiguration "Release" --ScSiteUrl "dummy"'
      #         Version: "1.3.0"
              
      # - job: Build_FE
      #   displayName: Build FE
      #   dependsOn: Init
      #   condition: Or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.FE'], 'true'),ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      #   steps:
      #     - task: Cake@2
      #       displayName: Generate and Build FE and Sitecore
      #       inputs:
      #         script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
      #         target: "Client :: Build"
      #         verbosity: "Quiet"
      #         arguments: '--BuildConfiguration "Release" --ScSiteUrl "dummy"'
      #         Version: "1.3.0"

          - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'PullRequest') }}:
              - template: /environment/azure/templates/steps/npm-audit.yml

      # - job: Unit_tests_BE
      #   displayName: Unit tests BE
      #   dependsOn: Init
      #   condition: Or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.BE'], 'true'),ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      #   steps:
      #     - task: Cake@2
      #       displayName: Run Unit tests
      #       inputs:
      #         script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
      #         target: "Server :: Tests"
      #         verbosity: "Quiet"
      #         Version: "1.3.0"
                
      # - job: Unit_tests_FE
      #   displayName: Unit tests FE
      #   dependsOn: Init
      #   condition: Or(eq(dependencies.check.outputs['CheckChanges.FE'], 'true'),ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      #   steps:
      #     - task: Cake@2
      #       displayName: Run Unit tests
      #       inputs:
      #         script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
      #         target: "Client :: Tests"
      #         verbosity: "Quiet"
      #         Version: "1.3.0"
          
          - task: PublishTestResults@2
            displayName: Publish test results
            inputs:
              testResultsFormat: "XUnit"
              testResultsFiles: "**/*.xml"
              searchFolder: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/tests"

          - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
            displayName: Publish code coverage
            inputs:
              codeCoverageTool: "Cobertura"
              summaryFileLocation: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/tests/coverage/**/*.xml"

          - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.Reason'],'PullRequest') }}:
              - task: Cake@2
                displayName: Publish Sitecore code
                inputs:
                  script: "src/build.cake"
                  target: "004-Publish"
                  verbosity: "Quiet"
                  arguments: '--BuildConfiguration "Release" --PublishingTargetDir "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sitecore" --ClientConfigDir "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/rendering/sitecore/config"'
                  Version: "1.3.0"

              - task: CopyFiles@2
                displayName: Copy Sitecore root files
                inputs:
                  SourceFolder: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/configs/Sitecore"
                  TargetFolder: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sitecore"
                  Contents: "**"

              - task: CopyFiles@2
                displayName: Copy transform files to separate artifact
                inputs:
                  SourceFolder: $(ArtifactsLocation)/sitecore/ # string. Source Folder. 
                  Contents: '**/*.transform' # string. Required. Contents. Default: '**'.
                  TargetFolder: $(ArtifactsLocation)/sitecore-transforms/ # string. Required. Target Folder. 

              - task: ArchiveFiles@2
                displayName: "Archive config file transform artifacts"
                inputs:
                  rootFolderOrFile: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sitecore-transforms/"
                  archiveFile: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sc/$(Build.BuildNumber)-transform.zip"
                  verbose: $(system.debug)
                  includeRootFolder: false

              - task: DeleteFiles@1
                displayName: Perform artifacts cleanup
                inputs:
                  SourceFolder: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sitecore"
                  RemoveDotFiles: true
                  Contents: |
                    **/obj/*
                    **/obj
                    **/*.wpp.targets
                    **/*.transform

              # this hack is needed as our jss app have different roots now.
              # hope in future it would be fixed
              - powershell: |
                  $distFolder = $(Get-Item "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sitecore/dist/").FullName;
                  $files = Get-ChildItem "$distFolder" -Recurse -Force;
                  $TestFolder = New-Item $(Join-Path $distFolder "Test") -Type Directory -Force;
                  $optimaFolder = New-Item $(Join-Path $distFolder "optimahealth") -Type Directory -Force;
                  $files | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($distFolder, "$($testFolder.FullName)/") -Force };
                  $files | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $_.FullName.Replace($distFolder, "$($optimaFolder.FullName)/") -Force };
                  $files | % { if (Test-Path $_.FullName) { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false } }
                displayName: Manually create folders for JSS app

              - task: ArchiveFiles@2
                displayName: "Archive Sitecore code artiffact"
                inputs:
                  rootFolderOrFile: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sitecore"
                  archiveFile: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sc/$(Build.BuildNumber).zip"
                  verbose: $(system.debug)
                  includeRootFolder: false

              - task: CopyFiles@2
                displayName: Copy Id root files
                inputs:
                  SourceFolder: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/configs/Id"
                  TargetFolder: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/id"
                  Contents: "**"

              - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
                displayName: Publish Sitecore
                inputs:
                  targetPath: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/sc"
                  artifactName: "SitecoreCode"

              - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
                displayName: Publish ID
                inputs:
                  targetPath: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/id"
                  artifactName: "SitecoreID"

      - job: SitecoreContent
        dependsOn: Init
        condition: eq(dependencies.check.outputs['ChangedFiles.SCContent'], 'true')
        steps:
          - template: /environment/azure/templates/steps/dotnet-cli.yml
            parameters:
              workingDir: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src"

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: Create Sitecore itempackage
            inputs:
              command: "custom"
              custom: "sitecore"
              arguments: "ser pkg create -o $(ArtifactsLocation)/w/test.itempackage"
              workingDirectory: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src"

          - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.Reason'],'PullRequest') }}:
              - task: CopyFiles@2
                displayName: Copy dotnet tools config
                inputs:
                  SourceFolder: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/.config/ # string. Source Folder. 
                  Contents: '**' # string. Required. Contents. Default: '**'.
                  TargetFolder: $(ArtifactsLocation)/w/.config/ # string. Required. Target Folder. 

              - task: CopyFiles@2
                displayName: Copy sitecore dotnet config
                inputs:
                  SourceFolder: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/ # string. Source Folder. 
                  Contents: 'sitecore.json' # string. Required. Contents. Default: '**'.
                  TargetFolder: $(ArtifactsLocation)/w/ # string. Required. Target Folder. 

              - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
                displayName: Publish Sitecore content
                inputs:
                  targetPath: "$(ArtifactsLocation)/w/"
                  artifactName: "SitecoreContent"
  
  ## Deployment stage
  - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.Reason'],'PullRequest') }}:
    - template: /environment/azure/templates/deployment.yml
```

There is error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduce the same issue with the similar YAML sample:

[image]

The cause of the issue is that we are not able to directly use dependencies expression in condition field.

To solve this issue, you need to change the following two points.

1. To use the variable in previous job, you can define variable to get the output variable in previous job.  Then you can use the new variable to set the condition.
2. The format you used to get the the output variable is incorrect.

Based on your situation, here is the correct sample:`dependencies.Init.outputs['ChangedFiles.FE']`.

Refer to the following example:

```
name: test-build$(Rev:.r)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*

  paths:
    exclude:
      - "environment/**/*"

schedules:
- cron: 0 19 * * 1-5
  displayName: evening-deployment
  branches:
    include: 
    - develop
  always: false # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.

pool:
  vmImage: "windows-latest"

variables:
  - group: shared-variables
  - name: ArtifactsLocation
    value: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/output"
  - name: NUGET_PACKAGES
    value: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nuget/packages"

stages:
  - stage: build
    displayName: Build solution
    jobs:
      - job: Init
        steps:
          - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'],'PullRequest') }}:
              - template: /environment/azure/templates/steps/validate-pr-title.yml
          - task: gitversion/setup@0
            displayName: Installing GitVersion tool
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "5.8.1"
      
          - task: ChangedFiles@1
            displayName: check
            condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
            inputs:
              rules: |
                [FE]
                **/*.json
                **/*.ts
                **/*.js
                **/*.tsx
                **/*.scss
                **/*.html
                **/*.css
                
                [BE]
                **/*.csproj
                **/*.cs
                **/*.yml
                **/*.yaml

                [SCContent]
                **/*.json
                **/*.yml
                **/*.yaml
          
          - task: GitVersion@5
            displayName: Generate GitVersion
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "5.8.1"
              runtime: "full"
              configFilePath: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/GitVersion.yml"
          
          - script: |
              echo deployInt: $(deployInt)
              echo deployQa: $(deployQa)
            displayName: Show variables for debug
            condition: eq(variables['system.debug'], 'true')

      - job: SitecoreCode
        dependsOn: Init
        variables:
          changes: $[dependencies.Init.outputs['ChangedFiles.FE'] ]
        steps:
          - task: UseNode@1
            displayName: Install correct Node.Js version
            inputs:
              version: "16.x"

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache cake packages
            inputs:
              key: 'cake | "$(Agent.OS)"'
              restoreKeys: |
                cake
              path: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/tools"

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache nuget modules
            inputs:
              key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json,!**/bin/**,!**/obj/**'
              restoreKeys: |
                nuget | "$(Agent.OS)"
                nuget
              path: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/packages"

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache nuget package reference modules
            inputs:
              key: 'nuget_pr | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/packages.lock.json'
              path: "$(NUGET_PACKAGES)"
              restoreKeys: |
                nuget_pr | "$(Agent.OS)"
                nuget_pr

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache node modules
            inputs:
              key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/package-lock.json'
              restoreKeys: |
                npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
                npm
              path: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/node_modules"

          - task: Cache@2
            displayName: Cache client node modules
            inputs:
              key: 'client_npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/rendering/package-lock.json'
              restoreKeys: |
                client_npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
                client_npm
              path: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/rendering/node_modules"

          - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
            displayName: Download license
            name: licenseFile
            inputs:
              secureFile: "license.xml"

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: Place license file under /src folder
            inputs:
              targetType: "inline"
              script: |
                Move-Item $(licenseFile.secureFilePath) "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/" -Force

          - template: /environment/azure/templates/steps/set-assembly-version.yml  

          - task: Cake@2
            displayName: Restore FE and Sitecore modules
            condition: Or(eq(variables['changes'], 'true'), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
            inputs:
              script: "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/src/build.cake"
              target: "Server :: Restore"
              verbosity: "Quiet"
              Version: "1.3.0"
```

Refer to the doc about [Use outputs in a different job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job)